# choosing the right data type and logic storing custom array like records(values)

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, optimization, sql-server-2012

say i have an object, it has an [id], [name] .. and some other data-info i call it meta , but the real `data` (it's value) is something like

```
x:2 , y:3 l:6, t:5, n:0 ,genr:plate; x:12 , y:32 l:26, t:45, n:1 ,genr:temp;
```

..... **x 20**

what is the most appropriate dataType ?

as i don't need to store each element in the array in it's own row /record but use it as a single record.

what will you choose as best practice, `string` ?  `byte array` ? not in the manner of mem consumption but performance and elegance

Comment: I'll assume they won't be used for any sorting or indexing or even filtering for that matter, but simply an additional info on the record. I would keep it as a simple string, and manage the logic behind the data in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data type comes in a pair

```
x:2 , y:3 l:6, t:5, n:0 ,genr:plate; x:12 , y:32 l:26, t:45, n:1 ,genr:temp;
```

And since the value can either be number or text, in C#, consider of using a `Dictionary<string, string>` to store one line. Thus, if you have 20+ lines of such, consider using `List` of `Dictionary<string, string>`, that is:

```
List<Dictionary<string,string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();
```

To add new data, create a dictionary, split the items, and then add the dictionary to a list:

```
string line = "x:2 , y:3 l:6, t:5, n:0 ,genr:plate; x:12 , y:32 l:26, t:45, n:1 ,genr:temp;";
Dictionary<string,string> linedata = new Dictionary<string,string>();
string[] lineitems = line.Split(new char[] { ',', ';', ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for (int i = 0; i < lineitems.Length; i += 2)
    linedata.Add(lineitems[i], lineitems[i + 1]);
data.Add(linedata); //each line is one single record in data List
```

Comment: cool trick on split option empty, never used it, you effortlessly stripped data from any separator,into to pure  via single command. very very nice indeed.

Comment: @כרמירפאל oh, yes. ;) you learn a new trick today. It took me quite a while before knowing that trick too...

Comment: and this is only one record List of dictionary , imagin situation i will need few records , List of <Lists of <dictionary (singel sqlDRow)>>`, did u ever use it ?

Comment: @כרמירפאל hmm... that seems like quite a lot of data. Now, I have never done such... normally one table row in my datatable will be mapped to one class in my program. So, it is not as complex as yours..

Comment: thanks - for being so informative today very helpful i did not want to step in till i know what's best way to handle data  thanks to @SimpleVar too.